# Rearrange object key based on array of keys javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
headers = ["no", "car","color","type"]

//json response
resp = [
    {"color":"green", "car":"bmw", "type": "suv", "no":"1"},
    {"color":"red", "car":"honda", "type": "sedan", "no":"2"},
    {"color":"blue", "car":"vw", "type": "truck", "no":"3"},
]
```

how can i rearrange the object key:val position based on `headers` array, so that i can render them in a table like so:

| no | car | color | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bmw | green | suv |
| 2 | honda | red | sedan |
| 3 | vw | blue | truck |

I need to use `resp` as below to render in a table:

```
resp.map((i,k) => (
  <tr key={k}> 
    <td>{i["no"]<td>
    <td>{i["car"]<td>
    <td>{i["color"]<td>
    <td>{i["type"]<td>
  <tr>
}))
```

Comment: Javascript objects don't have an "order" of keys so you can't "arrange" them. You need to come up with a different solution.

Comment: i've always rearrange them manually, but this time, there are >60 keys..

Comment: `resp.map( (i,k) => (<tr key={k}> <td>{i["no"]<td><td>{i["car"]<td><td>{i["color"]<td><td>{i["type"]<td><tr>})) ` literally hard-coded. as you can see the table, it won't be good for UX, if you dont rearrange the `resp`, if you just dynamically render them.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to 'order' the json for you to form the table. JavaScript doesn't guarantee order for objects, unlike arrays. You could use `map` on `resp` to form the table row based on the order of header list.

```
resp.map(data => {
  let row = '<tr>'
  headers.forEach(header => {
    row = row + '<td>' +data[header] + '</td>';
  });
  return row += '</tr>';
});
```

You just need to make sure, that the order of the items in `headers` is in the same order that you need.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any *arrangement* as Object keys in JavaScript aren't guaranteed to follow an order. If you need data in a particular order, you should use array.

For your current problem, you can iterate the `rows` and show it in order set by `headers`:

```js
const rows = [
  { color: 'green', car: 'bmw', type: 'suv', no: '1' },
  { color: 'red', car: 'honda', type: 'sedan', no: '2' },
  { color: 'blue', car: 'vw', type: 'truck', no: '3' },
]

const headers = ['no', 'car', 'color', 'type']

function App() {
  return (
    <table border={1}>
      <tr>
        {headers.map((header) => (
          <th>{header}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <tr>
          {headers.map((header) => (
            <td>{row[header]}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```